# Getting product attribute in downloadable controller in Magento

Tags: php, magento, controllers

I am trying to get the product attribute in my downloadable controller. I am working on an ebook store. I have created a custom module sp. I need the product attribute to watermark my ebooks.

The controller I am working on is Mage/Downloadable/controllers/DownloadController.php

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Please give us more of your code, else we cant help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends totally in which action you are.

If you have a look at the `linkAction` you can see how they obtain the product:

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0);
$linkPurchasedItem = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')->load($id, 'link_hash');
[...]
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($linkPurchasedItem->getProductId());
```

Now the product is loaded in the `$product` variable.
You can get product attributes as usual by `$product->getData('my_custom_attribute')` or `$product->getMyCustomAttribute`.

Comment: I can't till I have 15 reputation points otherwise I would mate. I have recently just registered

Comment: I upvoted your questions, now you can. Nice trade, isn't it :-)